# when i go from one activity to another activity i got null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, flags

when we go from one `activity` to another `activity` and remove current `activity` from stack, I get a `NullPointer exception`.
Lets suppose I have `class A` and `class B`. I'm going from A to B, and then back go from B to A and remove B activity from the stack using the `finish()` method or using `Flag_clear_Top`.

“A” Class as MainClass

```
public class MainClass extends Activity{

    Button callBTN;
    Button messageBTN;
    Button emailBTN;
    Button referBTN;
    TextView nameTXT;

    String name ;
    String email;
    String mobile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_class_layout);
         Intent myIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras();
        name = b.getString("name");
        email = b.getString("email");
        mobile = b.getString("mobile");

         Log.e("Name String", name);
            Log.e("email String", email);
            Log.e("mobile String", mobile);

          nameTXT=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name_TXT); 

            callBTN=(Button)findViewById(R.id.call_BTN);
            messageBTN=(Button)findViewById(R.id.message_BTN);
            emailBTN=(Button)findViewById(R.id.email_BTN);
            referBTN=(Button)findViewById(R.id.refer_BTN);

           nameTXT.setText(name);
           callBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 

            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ mobile));
                startActivity(callIntent);

            }

        });

           messageBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("MainClass","to find mobile number"+mobile);
                Intent intentSendMessage=new Intent(MainClass.this,SmsSender.class);
                intentSendMessage.putExtra("mobile_number",mobile);
                startActivity(intentSendMessage);

            }
        });
           emailBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intentEmail =new Intent(MainClass.this,EmailSender.class);
                intentEmail.putExtra("mail_Str",email);
                startActivity(intentEmail);

            }
        });

           referBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intentRefer=new Intent(MainClass.this,References.class);
                intentRefer.putExtra("emailAgent",email);

                startActivity(intentRefer);

            }
        });







    }

}
```

“B” class as References:

```
package com.cql.ins;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewDebug.FlagToString;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.cqlsys.help.UserFunctions;

public class References  extends Activity
{

    EditText nameEDt,emailEDt,phoneEDt,commentEDT;
    TextView errorTXT;
    Button referenceSendBTN;

    String emailReferAgent;


    // JSON Response node names
        private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "status";
        private static String KEY_Message ="message";
        private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.references_layout);

        Intent emailIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle d = emailIntent.getExtras();
        emailReferAgent = d.getString("emailAgent");

        nameEDt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name_Refer_EDt);
        emailEDt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email_Refer_EDT);
        phoneEDt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone_refer_EDT);
        commentEDT=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.comment_Refer_EDT);
        errorTXT=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.errorTXT);
        referenceSendBTN=(Button)findViewById(R.id.refer_send_BTN);



        referenceSendBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String nameReferStr = nameEDt.getText().toString();
                String emailReferStr = emailEDt.getText().toString();
                String phoneReferStr =phoneEDt.getText().toString();
                String commentReferStr =commentEDT.getText().toString();    

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

                JSONObject json =userFunction.referUser(nameReferStr, emailReferStr, phoneReferStr,commentReferStr,emailReferAgent);

                // check for  response
                try {
                    if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                        errorTXT.setText("hello");
                        String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                        Log.e("REferences Status Tag", res);

                        if(Boolean.parseBoolean(res) == true){
                            // user successfully submit
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intentbackMainClass=new Intent(References.this,MainClass.class);
                            //intentbackMainClass.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                            startActivity(intentbackMainClass);
                            finish();
                        }else{
                            // Error in submit the data
                            errorTXT.setText("Error occured in registration");
                        }


                    }
            }
                 catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

But I get the following exception:

** threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
    01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cqlsys.insagent/com.cql.ins.MainClass}: java.lang.NullPointerException **

```
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at com.cqlsys.insagent.MainClass.onCreate(MainClass.java:39)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-19 02:43:27.507: E/AndroidRuntime(13801):    ... 11 more
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: on which line u are getting this error?

Comment: If you are not passing bundle, and using  intent.putExtra ("Str", str) to pass, you can retrieve it using intent.getStringExtra("Str");

Comment: Do you get all the values of bundle printed in your logcat ?

Comment: @Krishna:when i using intent in class References for call to previous activity ,that is already in stack , i got error:
my code as
// user successfully submit

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       //Intent intentbackMainClass=new Intent(References.this,MainClass.class);
       
            //  intentbackMainClass.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
             // startActivity(intentbackMainClass);

Comment: I got error on
01-19 04:36:47.018: E/REferences Status Tag(14045): true
01-19 04:36:47.258: E/AndroidRuntime(14045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 04:36:47.258: E/AndroidRuntime(14045): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cqlsys.insagent/com.cqlsys.insagent.MainClass}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I guess its because the values of these are null,

```
   name = b.getString("name");
    email = b.getString("email");
    mobile = b.getString("mobile");
```

But you try to print them in the Log here,

```
            Log.e("Name String", name);
            Log.e("email String", email);
            Log.e("mobile String", mobile);
```

The thing is, I don't see you pass the extras from where you call the startActivity() and hence they are null here and you get the exception.

If you don't want your log to crash your app then edit your log like this,

```
                Log.e("Name String", name+"");
                Log.e("email String", email+"");
                Log.e("mobile String", mobile+"");
```

So that this prints "null" if the values are null, if not it does print the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am Not Sure but this Can happen if you are not passing anything from Activity B and Getting "b" as Null.

Instead of Below Code. you should first check whether **b==null or Not** after you can get all the Values you want through Intent.

so Instead

```
   Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras();
        name = b.getString("name");
        email = b.getString("email");
        mobile = b.getString("mobile");
```

try With Below Code.

```
  Bundle b = myIntent.getExtras();
  if(b!=null){

            name = b.getString("name");
            email = b.getString("email");
            mobile = b.getString("mobile");
  }
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh
-Thanks for reply,I already do this , but error is still.I explain how error occur..I go from "MainClass" activity to "References" activity and again back from "References" activity to MainClass Activity. My "References " got JSON response successfully.-
**try {if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {   errorTXT.setText("hello");String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
if(Boolean.parseBoolean(res) == true){Intent intentbackMainClass=newIntent (References.this,MainClass.class);intentbackMainClass.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);startActivity(intentbackMainClass);
}**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use,getExtras above `setContentView()`

```
  Intent emailIntent = getIntent();
  Bundle d = emailIntent.getExtras();
  emailReferAgent = d.getString("emailAgent");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nameTXT.setText(name);
```

This seem to be the problem as you are trying to set the name text and if name is returning no value then it will generate the `nullpointerexception`.

Please check if you are getting value when coming from class B to A.